# Qt creator version 5.7.0 error:Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details. Error while building/deploying project..

Tags: c++, qt, error-handling, compiler-errors, mingw

I download Qt version 5.7.0 with offline installer.I try to run a simple hello World program but it dosen't work and Qt gives this error:
Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
Error while building/deploying project prova (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
When executing step "Make".
I'm programming in c++.
I download the compiler minGW cause it was missing.Nothing change.I tried to download all the package of minGW but I don't know hot to set up the compiler and how to eliminate this error.I need to use QT for Univeristy.Can someone help me?Thanks you all.Waiting for your reply see you!

Comment: You should not download the Visual Studio binaries for Qt if you are using mingw. These will not work.

Comment: The offline installer contains MinGW - install that version to ensure it is compatible with the Qt build. Obviously, the MS compiler build is **not compatible** with MinGW...

Comment: But I don't download Visual Studio binaries.I reset my computer and I downloaded Qt.So why this error?Qt is doing everything in automatic!I know that MS complier is not compatible with MinGW but what the heck why I have this setted as default?How can Install MinGW?I said that I have already installed it,but I don't know if I did the right thing..I'm not understanding what is happening.I'm sorry!

Comment: Uninstall everything, and install it again but be careful - chose the https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.7/5.7.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw530-5.7.0.exe offline installer, and when installing, check the option to install Mingw, then everything should be set up for you automatically.